# Why does my java script function stop half way without reason

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Please note that this page is only for a school project, its not meant to function as a payment page.
My code executes on submit, but only gets as far as checking for the name, if there is a problem with the date or cvc code it skips it and continues as if it received a true value. Any help would be great as my deadline is approaching. All i need it to do is run the entirety of the code.
An example of the code as it it now can be found at
http://www.come-get-me-games.x11s.org/confirm_booking.php

The code for the area is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check(){
        var num = document.getElementById('cardNumber');        
        var name = document.getElementById('nameOnCard');
        var dater = document.getElementById('expDate');
        var cvc = document.getElementById('cvc');

        if(num.value==="" || num.value===null){
            alert('Please enter your card number');
            return false;
        }else if (name.value==="" || name.value===null){
            alert('Please enter the as it appears on the card');
            return false;
        }else if (dater.value==="dd/mm/yyy" || dater.value === "" || dater.value===null){
            alert('Please Enter a Date');
            return false;
        }else if (cvc.value==="" || cvc.value===null){
            alert('Enter the CVC number, this can be found as the \n last 3 digits on the number on the back of your code');
            return false;
        } else {
            var check = confirm('Are you sure you wish to purchase these tickets');
            if(check === true){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>

</table>
</div>
    <div style="text-align:left;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:10px;width:480px"> 
        <?php echo "Total ticket price &pound".$price ?><br>
        <br>
        <h3>Payment</h3>
        <form method="post" action="scripts/ticket_buy.php" onSubmit="return check()">
        <div class="item_container">
            Card Number <input value="" type="text" id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" style="position:absolute;right:0px" /><br />
            Name On Card<input value="" type="text" id="nameOnCard" style="position:absolute;right:0px" name="nameOnCard" /><br />
            Expiry Date<input value="" type="date" id="epxDate" style="position:absolute;right:0px" name="expDate" /><br />
            CVC Number<input value="" type="text" id="cvc" style="position:absolute;right:0px" name="cvc">
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $eventIDwanted ?>' name="eID">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $performanceIDwanted ?>" name="pID">
            <input type="submit" value="Purchase" class="button_default" style="width:480px">
        </div>
        </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Try changing you `===` to `==` since `===` does not perform and data type conversions

Comment: Your page doesn't load for me.

Comment: `<input value="" type="date" id="epxDate" style="position:absolute;right:0px" name="expDate" />` -- id is misspelled.

Comment: Any chance of getting a small jsfiddle going of this?  Your complete code is pretty damn hard to read.  And the website you linked seems to be down (or at least not responding at all).

Comment: didnt work. Sorry about the indentation, im still only a learner, im trying

Comment: check comment of @Juhana

Comment: If you are not already doing this, try running the code, line-by-line, in Chrome Developer Tools. Your problem may be much easier to find that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the id for date. In your JS you have expDate while in input you have epxDate

```
 Expiry Date<input value="" type="date" id="expDate" style="position:absolute;right:0px" name="expDate" /><br />
```

Working <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/YEH5p/)</kbd>

Just a note : whenever your JS seems not to be working use firebug console or chrome console to see if there is any JS error or not.

Comment: Thanks very much, You are a life saver i can now get back to finishing this site befor its due in :D Feel a bit of a tard now

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling epxDate as opposed to expDate. Also if you have the script sitting at the top without making sure DOM is ready that can create issues. So please either move it to the bottom or load it on DOm ready or load (not recommended).